# JavaFX: How to set a TiteledPane selected/opened by default

Tags: java, javafx, accordion, pane

I am working on a project using java and **javaFX**, i need to know if there is a way to have the first `TiteledPane`  in the `Accordion` opened **by default**..

I mean when the stage is **loaded**, the first `TiteledPane` is selected and its content showed **without any user's intervention**. i tried all suggested methods but no one look like what i want. As i see also no described one in the official documentation or given in this site or other is like.

---

**IN ADDITION:**

here is my approach:(Code java and FXML)

```
@FXML
private Accordion accord_pane;
@FXML
private TitledPane pane_ara,pane_sci,pane_soc,pane_art,pane_spo,pane_fra,pane_ang;

...

pane_ara.setText("TitledPane A");
pane_sci.setText("TitledPane B");

accord_pane.setExpandedPane(pane_ara);
```

---

```
               <Accordion fx:id="accord_pane" layoutX="20.0" layoutY="100.0" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="680.0">
                  <panes>
                    <TitledPane fx:id="pane_ara" animated="false">
                         <content>
                            <Pane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                               <children>
                                  <ImageView fx:id="img_unit_ara" fitHeight="250.0" fitWidth="650.0" layoutX="15.0" layoutY="15.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                                     <image>
                                        <Image url="@temp_5.png" />
                                     </image>
                                  </ImageView>
                               </children>
                            </Pane>
                         </content>
                    </TitledPane>
                      <TitledPane fx:id="pane_sci" animated="false">
                         <content>
                            <Pane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                               <children>
                                  <ImageView fx:id="img_unit_sci" fitHeight="190.0" fitWidth="650.0" layoutX="15.0" layoutY="15.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                                     <image>
                                        <Image url="@temp_3.png" />
                                     </image>
                                  </ImageView>
                               </children>
                            </Pane>
                         </content>
                      </TitledPane>
                     </panes>
                   </Accordion>
```

here is the exception:

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/Malek%20Boubakri/Google%20Drive/workspace/Sirat/bin/vue/Enseignant.fxml
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
at vue.Enseignant.start(Enseignant.java:18)
at vue.Index.stageCtrlHandler(Index.java:85)
at controleur.MenuCtrl.click_btn(MenuCtrl.java:69)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.access$8100(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$350(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$$Lambda$165/775736639.get(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$145(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$36/2117255219.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at controleur.EnsCtrl.initialize(EnsCtrl.java:301)
    ... 54 more
```

here is the text from documentation that i lean on.

> **public final void setExpandedPane(TitledPane value)**
>
> The expanded TitledPane that is currently visible. While it is
> technically possible to set the expanded pane to a value that is not
> in getPanes(), doing so will be treated by the skin as if expandedPane
> is null. If a pane is set as the expanded pane, and is subsequently
> removed from getPanes(), then expanded pane will be set to null, if
> possible. (This will not be possible if you have manually bound the
> expanded pane to some value, for example).

If any thing is not clear please just comment. Any suggestion will be helpful..Thanks

Comment: "I tried all suggested methods". Please create a [MCVE] showing what you tried and [edit] your question to include it.

Comment: Please check it again, i do what i could and i'm really need help here.. thanks

Comment: Your code looks correct. I guess you didn't read the link in my previous comment: please post a [MCVE].

Comment: I don't get what i should add or remove from the question.. 
and -2 is all what i got.. if possible, please tell me what wrong in my question @James_D and thanks.
sorry for my bad english..

Comment: As it says in the link, your example code should be *minimal* (only what you need to show the problem, eg you need an accordion and at most 2 titled panes (not 7), and nothing else); it should be *complete* (complete classes and fxml files, enough to actually execute it, not code snippets like you have), and *verifiable* (compiles and runs and demonstrates the problem). Start from scratch, create a ***new project*** that only has an accordion with two titled panes, and try to get it to expand one titled pane at startup. If you can't, then post the code.

Comment: And only now do you even mention that you get an exception? Don't you think this would have been useful information before?

Comment: hhhh.. my fault, i think it's complete right now.

Comment: In what possible sense is that "complete"?

Comment: I mean "correct question form" :(

Comment: can you please post codes from `Enseignant` class especially line 15 all to 85, okay.

Comment: Do you mean Enseignant controler class or the FXML file??

Comment: just the controller class @MalekBoubakri

Comment: i think the problem is outside the code because when i tested it in another new package (in netbeans) it works!!! i'm using eclipse mars and i really think to move back  to luna.. :/ i dont know if putting the workpace in google cloud can damage something! i noticed that when i start eclipse google cloud get crashed..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

About the code difficulties it's **highly recommended to refresh your project** everytime you work on then save an FXML file from javaFX scene builder because eclipse dont do that automatically.

if you still hve some code problemes,this exemple is verified:

```
@FXML
private Accordion accord;
@FXML
private TitledPane pane1,pane2;

//codes in controller.intialize()
...
    pane1.setText("TitledPane A");
    pane2.setText("TitledPane B");
    accord.setExpandedPane(pane1);
```

And about the cloud problem you mentioned in the comment, as i know there is **no harm on putting the workspace in google** drive folder.May be it would be better if you do backup every time you finish a chapter of code, because sometimes drive crash when he try to load a file already used by another program.

Answer (score 27):

For those who want to include the default expanded pane in the FXML rather than in code:

```
<Accordion expandedPane="$myPane">
    <panes>
      <TitledPane fx:id="myPane">
          ...
      </TitledPane>
      <TitledPane>
          ...
      </TitledPane>
    </panes>
</Accordion>
```

Comment: Works great! Unfortunately SceneBuilder doesn't seem to expose the "expandedPane" property which makes it difficult to discover.

Comment: Also scene builder overwrites this attribute on save :(